# Developer workload management software: recommendations?

Tags: issue-tracking

In my place, we use two issue tracking tools, one for production bugs, and another for issues on projects in development. These tools are good for managers. However, at an individual level, other work can also arrive through desk visits, email, or the phone, and those allocating the work aren't always interested in issue tracking systems.

I've recently rolled off an 18-month project where I got into a cycle of overtime, and I found that I didn't always have good visibility of all work assigned to me. As a result, I was always very busy, and felt constantly laden down with work, but didn't have the clear data to show my manager (or, ironically, the time to stop and gather the information!).

A handwritten list, updated at the end of each day, is a good start, but can anyone recommend better tools to help me get a clear view of my own workload? Ideally, I'm thinking of software tools for developers, which could incorporate estimates, but all suggestions welcome.

Thanks, Paddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one in an unrated answer to another question:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx

And so far it seems to be reasonably good, the kind of thing I had in mind (I'll compare to Taskcoach as well though).

I think one of these two will be the planning tool I need, so combined with a notepad/spreadsheet to keep track of time spent, I reckon this answers my question, thanks lads.

Answer (score 1):

There are few software which can help keeping track of how you use your time by taking snapshot of your screen and monitor the active processes. You may be interested in [How do you track your hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707/how-do-you-track-your-hours). I also find a small notebook to be useful in keeping a simple todo list.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Taskcoach](http://www.taskcoach.org). It allows you to organise and track your projects and development time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for. It takes all sorts of activities into account - e.g. meetings, absences, support etc - as well as any project related tasks. Also has a timesheeting module:
[Context](http://www.blackstairsmountains.com/BlackstairsHome/Pages/Context.aspx)